# Spark UI job durations are inconsistent

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm creating a Spark application using pyspark and am finding it difficult to monitor its performance through the Spark UI, since the jobs duration don't reflect the time I measured in the program itself.

I ran my code in a Jupyter Notebook.

My first cell has the follwoing code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession \
            .builder \
            .appName('Parquet Load Tests') \
            .getOrCreate()
spark
```

the second, reads the file:

```
%%time
df = spark.read.parquet('/path/to/my/file.parquet/')
```

and the third counts the number of rows of the dataframe:

```
%%time
df.count()
```

While read and count time on the notebook were 5.78s and 1m 28s, on Spark UI, these times were 1s and 6s.

Here's a printscreen from Spark UI:
[image: Spark UI jobs]

Does someone know what is happening here?

Comment: The first statement wouldn't be even reflected in UI.

Comment: Which one? The session startup or the parquet file read? The latter one is reflected

Comment: Interesting, it actually starts a job.